# Is it possible to set the selected value in a Telerik RadDropDownList in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

Is it possible to set the selected value/item in a Telerik RadDropDownList in Javascript?

I'm looking at the documentation http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/dropdownlist-clientsideprogramming-clientsidebasic.html and it seems there is no documented way to do this simple and essential task.

Is it simply not in the documentation? Tried searching the forums as well to no avail.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `select()` or `set_selected(true)` function. [Here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/dropdownlistitem-client-object-api.html) is the documentation.

```
<telerik:RadDropDownList ID="RadDropDownList1" runat="server">
    <Items>
        <telerik:DropDownListItem runat="server" Text="One" Value="1" />
        <telerik:DropDownListItem runat="server" Text="Two" Value="2" />
        <telerik:DropDownListItem runat="server" Text="Three" Value="3" />
    </Items>
</telerik:RadDropDownList>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        var dropdownlist = $find("<%= RadDropDownList1.ClientID %>");
        var item = dropdownlist.findItemByValue("3");
        item.select();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dropdownlist = document.getElementById('<%= RadDropDownList1.ClientID %>');
if (dropdownlist != null) {
    dropdownlist .children[0].children[0].innerHTML = "3 - Low";
    dropdownlist .children[0].children[0].setAttribute("class", "rddlFakeInput");
}
```

No other solutions worked on my project !!
3 days for the item.selected = true;
it's not acceptable, so JavaScript in 20 minutes

Comment: Win's answer worked fine for me. Did you by change left the `#` before the ID?